# Finding birth record of Pierre Louis Oscar Cordier, Frenchman who married (1869) and died (1882) in London?

Tags: england, military-records, france, london

I'm researching my girlfriend's family tree and I've hit a brick wall in France as I have absolutely no experience using french records.

I have traced back to Pierre Louis Oscar/Oscard Cordier born in "France" in abt 1843.

I have the following records for him in England:

**1869** marriage register, married Emily Elizabeth Smith at St Mary le Bow, London. This shows he was a widower, and his father was Jean Baptiste Cordier, an Officer in the French Army:
[image: Marriage register]

**1871** census, in Marylebone, London:
[image: 1871 census]

**1881** census, in Camberwell, London, where his birth place looks to be "Vendée" although a second opinion would be great.
[image: 1881 census]

**1882** death certificate, in Hackney, London:
[image]

---

I know that with all French family research, I need to know precisely ( i.e. town and department) where he was born as there is no National Register like the English BMD. But that's all I really know.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction in regards to finding birth/baptism records and anything else relating to him.

**To clarify: I'm looking for a birth record related to Pierre Louis Oscar Cordier**

Comment: As much as possible I think that you should try to keep your question focussed on finding an answer to the specific question of "Finding birth/baptism record for Pierre Louis Oscar Cordier - some of the other information that you would like to also know may come out of answering that but the strength of this site is answering specific questions.  We've been having some discussion about this recently in Meta: http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/dealing-with-broad-questions-that-ask-for-any-information-about-person-family

Comment: If we only have a GRO index (or any index) of births, marriages, and deaths but not the certificates, we do not know for sure if the index refers to the person we are looking for.  We only assume or suspect that could be the right person.

Comment: @PolyGeo In this case I don't think the first question to ask is "finding birth/baptism". I think there are lots of other things that need to be investigated - e.g. his immigration to England, his first marriage - before delving into French birth records. I agree the question needs to be focussed for this format, but sometimes the process of focussing the question can be as constructive as the question itself.

Comment: @vervet My point is that if you are making an assumption, you need to be *aware* of what that assumption is.  I don't care how unusual a name is -- there is always the possibility that there might be more than one person bearing that name.  Being careless about how we know what we know is a major factor in how we create brick walls for ourselves. You say we can't be sure even if we have a certificate -- so -- that holds true even more for an index entry, which has far less information extracted than the original record has.

Comment: "Finding birth/baptism record" is just one of a number of questions that could be asked and I think it is best to try and tease them apart into separate questions.  For example, I think the question about reading the place name on the 1881 census would make a nice separate question.  And I think "Seeking military records for Jean Baptiste Cordier, French Army Officer?" would make another excellent one because his postings might point to possible birthplaces for his son.

Comment: @polygeo I'll create some new questions and amend this one soon

Comment: Edited the question, thanks @vervet for helping with the images, they don't seem to embed when I'm on my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days, there is quite a lot already indexed for France through various sites. Often my first stop if a proper location is not known is to look at [GeoPatronyme](http://www.geopatronyme.com/) and get a feel for how common the name is and where distributed.

Then [Genealogie.com](http://www.genealogie.com/v4/genealogie/Search.mvc/Search). This is a pay site, but with a little cleverness we can get it to give us quite a lot of info, then go look at the appropriate archives (e.g. Archives de la Vendée ).

In this case, I searched 'nom' as Cordier, 'prénom' as 'Pierre', and then on the results page, under 'Initiale du prénom' chose 'O' to pick up the 'Oscar'. Right away, up to the top of the list bubbles a Pierre Louis Oscar Cordier born sometime between 1825 and 1850 in La Roche-sur-Yon. Narrowing it down by going back to the search and putting in 'Cordier', plus a one-year range, shows this man was born 1842.

Instead of paying to see it on that site, we're going to go to the [Vendée archives](http://archives.vendee.fr/Consulter/Archives-numerisees) and try to pick it up on their free Etat civil database.

Unfortunately they don't make it easy to directly link, but a quick check of the index for 1842 (at the back of the births section, not right at the back) shows me he's there, number 192 (image 92 of 357).

His birth was registered 11 October 1842 - the son of Jean Baptiste Alexandre Cordier, aged 47, occupation something gendarmerie?, and Jeanne Pauline Mora.

---

in the case where a birth can't be found, tracking down a marriage in France is another way to find  information on birth place and parents. His first marriage etc. can be tracked down as follows.

A popular American pay site, as well as geneanet.org, lead me to a possible marriage for him Ille-et-Vilaine.  Using Geneanet gets me to the exact location - Rennes.

Rennes is one of the cases where the records are on the [Municipal Archives](http://www.archives.rennes.fr/archives-et-inventaires/archives-en-ligne/etat-civil/) site for the city. Judging by his age and the fact that he remarried in 1869, I went for the 1863-1872 Tables (ten-year indexes), which show the marriage was 21 Jan 1865, to Sainte Rousseau. To find the original - left hand side of page 8 on the 1865 marriages).

This shows this is definitely the same man b. 1842, with the same parents. He is, at this point, a tobacconist, and living in Hédé (now Hédé-Bazouges) although the marriage took place in Rennes. His parents, both who seem to be living, (father 'retired officer of the gendarmerie') were also living in Hédé. His wife's family were resident in Rennes.

(Obviously if we found the marriage first, we would then use this information to locate and double-check the birth record)

---

For my final trick, we can hop over to the [Ille-et-Villaine archives](http://archives-en-ligne.ille-et-vilaine.fr/thot_internet/FrmSommaireFrame.asp):

'Etat civil' to find the possible death of his wife, but hidden under genealogy are 'recensements' - the *census*. Not often used in French genealogy because it's mostly unindexed, but Hédé was quite small - only 35 pages in the 1866.

On page 12 is this little bit of interest:
Louis Cordier, aged 23, tobacconist, listed with a group of seemingly unrelated people (a widow and her child, some older women), and then an 8-month old child, Adele Cordier.

Adele was b. Hede as 'Adele Louise Cordier', 1 December 1865, daughter of 'Louis Pierre', aged 23, tobacconist, and Sainte Rosseau.  Sainte Rosseau, wife of Louis Cordier, died 13 December 1865, aged just 20.

Comment: Excellent find - you have no idea how much time I spent fiddling around with the Vendee archives site. I have a feeling this may give rise to a question on French palaeography ;)

Comment: Wow, UNBELIEVABLE. Thank you so much! I think I'll need to make a new translation question now...Edit: Second that @vervet

Comment: No problem, Danny! Found his first marriage, so added that - so much more information on French records, so marriages can be another way to find birth location, date, parents names, etc.

Comment: My French lot originate from the Vendee, so I'm familiar with both the process and the frustration of pinning down the exact birthplace ;)

Comment: I never realised how good french records are...once you actually find them

Comment: @nkjt Can you guide me how to use the Ille-et-Vilaine Archives? I searched Genealogie for Raymond Cordier, and sorted by his middle name E (Raymond Ernest Cordier) and there seems to be a hit for a death in 1875-1900 I used your method and got it down to 1894. But on the Ille-et-Vilaine archives I can't find anything? What am I doing wrong. I go to: Registres paroissiaux et état civil > type in Ille-et-Vilaine and the dates 1894 but he is'nt listed. What is it i'm not understanding...

Comment: Ille-et-Vilaine is the department, you need to figure out the place. If you know where it might have been, you can filter by commune - e.g. searching for 'Rennes' gives me a marriage hit for Raymond Ernest Alexandre CORDIER, and for 'Hédé' shows me the death. On the Ille-et-Vilaine archives, when picking places, I find it easiest to press the '?' button next to 'Lieu' or 'Commune' and select from a list - it seems very fussy about orthography.