# Translation & Transcription Request, French birth record from 1842

Tags: birth-records, palaeography, france, translation

I am looking for a translation and transcription for a french record that @nkjt kindly found in [Finding birth record of Pierre Louis Oscar Cordier, Frenchman who married (1869) and died (1882) in London?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/finding-birth-record-of-pierre-louis-oscar-cordier-frenchman-who-married-1869).

It will not link directly, so to view the original image, go to the [Vendee Archives, État civil](http://www.archinoe.fr/cg85/etatcivil.php) > Choisir une commune: Roche-sur-Yon (La) > Choisir une collection: Etat civil > Naissances, Mariages, Décès, 1842 > enter page 92/357 in bottom right corner.

[image]

I really wish I could even attempt it but I don't know any french let alone how to read old style handwriting.

**A translation and transcription courtesy of a reddit user:**

**Transcription:**

"L’an mil huit cent quarante deux, le douze octobre à une heure après-midi, par devant nous Pierre Ferdinand Guyot adjoint au Maire de la commune de Bourbon Vendée chef lieu du département de la Vendée, auquel le (____) délégué par arrêté du sept décembre mil huit cent quarante, la fonction d’officier de l’état civil de la dite commune est comparu (_____) Jean Baptiste Alexandre Cordier âgé de quarante sept ans lieutenant de gendarmerie à la résidence de cette ville y demeurant rue Dauphine, lequel nous a présenté un enfant du sexe masculin, né le jour d’hier à six heure du matin de lui déclarant (___) naître et de Jeanne Pauline Mora son épouse en légitime mariage et auquel il a déclaré vouloir donner les prénoms de Pierre Louis Oscar. Les dites déclaration et présentation faites en présence des (_____) Narcisse Bouchaud âgé de quarante huit ans, Maréchal des Logis de Gendarmerie et Pierre Alexandre Constantin Geute âgé de quarante-trois ans, brigadier de cette même armée, demeurant les deux en cette ville. (____ __ ____) signé avec nous le présent acte de naissance après que lecture leur en a été faite."

**Translation:**

"The year 1842, on October 12th at 1 pm, in front of us, Pierre Ferdinand Guyot, deputy mayor of Bourbon Vendée, county-town of the department of Vendée, to whom the (____) delegated by the order of September 7th 1840 to the function of registrar of the said town, has appeared (____) Jean Baptiste Alexandre Cordier, aged 47, lieutenant of the gendarmerie of this town, residing on rue Dauphine, who presented to us a male child born yesterday at 6 in the morning of him he declared (____) being born and of Jeanne Pauline Mora his spouse in legitimate marriage and to whom he has declared wanting to give the names of Pierre Louis Oscar. The said déclarations and présentations were made in the présence of the (____) Narcisse Bouchaud aged 48, sergeant of the gendarmerie and Pierre Alexandre Constantin Gente aged 43, sergeant of the same army, both of them living in this town. (____ __ ____) signed with us this birth certificate after it was read to them."

If anyone else can add to this or fill in the blanks add to this or create a new answer.

Comment: It's amazing seeing the Cordier signature. It is almost identical to my girlfriends. (Jean Baptiste Alexandre Cordier's 3x great granddaughter)  she does the exact same curls over it.

Comment: The direct link to the Vendee Archives site did not work, so I added brief instructions to get to the page.

Comment: @vervet Thank you, I didn't know if it would.

Comment: Should I add the translation I've added to the question as an answer? Or only once it is fully transcribed if no one else has?

Comment: I think having most of the translation/transcription in your question makes it the ideal form to get a few answers from others to fill in the gaps, and give you an opportunity to click the Accept (green tick) next to whichever one you think helped you the most in completing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My French is rather rusty but I think I've managed to fill in the gaps:

> L’an mil huit cent quarante deux, le douze octobre à une
>   heure après-midi, par devant nous Pierre Ferdinand Guyot
>   adjoint au Maire de la commune de Bourbon Vendée, chef
>   lieu du département de la Vendée, auquel le **dit maire a** délégué
>   par arrêté du sept décembre mil huit cent quarante, la
>   fonction D’officier de l’état civil de la dite commune est
>   comparu **le sieur** Jean Baptiste Alexandre Cordier âgé
>   de quarante sept ans lieutenant de Gendarmerie à
>   la Résidence de cette ville y demeurant
>   rue Dauphine, lequel nous a présenté un enfant du
>   sexe masculin, né le jour d’hier à six heure du
>   matin de lui déclarant **en sa maison** et de Jeanne
>   Pauline Mora son épouse en légitime mariage et
>   auquel il a déclaré vouloir donner les prénoms de
>   Pierre Louis Oscar. Les dites déclaration et
>   présentation faites en présence des **sieurs** Narcisse
>   Bouchaud âgé de quarante huit ans, Maréchal des
>   Logis de Gendarmerie et Pierre Alexandre Constantin
>   Geute âgé de quarante-trois ans, brigadier de cette
>   même armée, demeurant les deux en cette ville. **Et ont le
>
>   père et les Témoins** signé avec nous le présent acte de
>   naissance après que lecture leur en a été faite."

Translation:

"The year 1842, on October 12th at 1 pm, in front of us, Pierre Ferdinand Guyot, deputy mayor of Bourbon Vendée, county-town of the department of Vendée, to whom the **said mayor** delegated by the order of September 7th 1840 to the function of registrar of the said town, has appeared **Mr** Jean Baptiste Alexandre Cordier, aged 47, lieutenant of the gendarmerie of this town, residing on rue Dauphine, who presented to us a male child born yesterday at 6 in the morning, **from him the informant, in his house**, and of Jeanne Pauline Mora his spouse in legitimate marriage and to whom he has declared wanting to give the names of Pierre Louis Oscar. The said declarations and presentations were made in the presence of **Messrs** Narcisse Bouchaud aged 48, sergeant of the gendarmerie and Pierre Alexandre Constantin Gente aged 43, sergeant of the same army, both of them living in this town. **And the father and the witnesses have** signed with us this birth certificate after it was read to them."